# Update EmployeeID Attribute using csv

Tags: powershell

Here is the code i using to update the ad user from csv

```
$Users = Import-CSV "C:\PSS\UserList.csv"
$Results = $Users | ForEach-Object {
 try {
     $User = Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -eq $_.mail}
     if ($null -ne $User -and $null -eq $_.EmployeeID) {
         try {
             Set-ADUser $User.SamAccountName -EmployeeID $_.EmployeeID
             $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty Status -Value "Complete"
         } catch {
             $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
             $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty Status -Value $ErrorMessage
         }
     } else {
         $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty Status -Value "Skipped"
     }
 } catch {
     $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
     $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty Status -Value $ErrorMessage
 }
}
$Failed = $Results | Where-Object {$_.Status -ne "Complete" -and $_.Status -ne "Skipped"}
Write-Host "Failed Accounts: $($Failed.Count)"
$Results | Export-Csv -Path "UserList-Results.csv"
```

The output results in UserList-Results.csv are empty and the employee id can't be set in AD. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that your loop doesn not output anything to be collected in $Results.
Both `Set-ADUser` and `Add-Member` do not provide output by default, unless you append switch `-PassThru` to these cmdlet.

Also, to be able to handle exceptions (both terminating and non-terminating) in the `catch` blocks, you need use `-ErrorAction Stop` on the lines that can throw an exception.

Without changing your code too much, below should work for you

```
$Users   = Import-CSV -Path "C:\PSS\UserList.csv" # assuming there are fields `mail` and `EmployeeID` in this file
$Results = $Users | ForEach-Object {
    # store in a variable because in a catch block, $_ is the actual exception object, no longer the user from the CSV
    $currentUser = $_  
    # Get-ADUser by default returns objects with these properties:
    # DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
    $User = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($currentUser.mail)'" -Properties EmailAddress, EmployeeID -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($User) {
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currentUser.EmployeeID)) {
            Write-Warning "Field EmployeeID was empty for user '$($User.Name)'. Skipped"
            $currentUser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value "Skipped" -PassThru
        }
        elseif ($User.EmployeeID -eq $currentUser.EmployeeID) {
            Write-Host "EmployeeID already set to '$($User.EmployeeID)' for user '$($User.Name)'. Skipped"
            $currentUser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value "Skipped" -PassThru
        }
        else {
            try {
                $User | Set-ADUser -EmployeeID $currentUser.EmployeeID -ErrorAction Stop
                Write-Host "EmployeeID for user '$($User.Name)' set to '$($currentUser.EmployeeID)'" -ForegroundColor Green
                $currentUser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value "Complete" -PassThru
            } 
            catch {
                Write-Warning "Error setting the UserID property on user '$($User.Name)'"
                $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
                $currentUser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value $ErrorMessage -PassThru
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "The user with email address '$($currentUser.mail)' could not be found"
        $currentUser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value "Skipped" -PassThru
    }
}

$Failed = @($Results | Where-Object {$_.Status -ne "Complete" -and $_.Status -ne "Skipped"})
Write-Host "Failed Accounts: $($Failed.Count)"

$Results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\PSS\UserList-Results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: in line 24 it said it cant bind to “InputObject” because it is empty. Is it my excel problem?Sorry i have zero coding skill. @Theo

Comment: @troya Sorry, my bad.. I totally forgot that the `$_` automatic variable inside a catch block is in fact the exception object, not the object from the CSV anymore.. Changed the code now. Then you comment about Excel, but you are importing a CSV right?

Comment: yes i am importing a CSV. Is there any requirement in excel? @Theo

Comment: @troya Excel is quite a different file format and much more difficult to manage in PowerShell. CSV is the format usually used when importing data into Excel or other software. BTW, dit my updated code work for you?

Comment: the output result become like this `"amyyu@yang.local","1111","???????:?mail -eq amyyu@yang.local'?????:?syntax error???:?10??"`  @Theo

Comment: Also, i checked the employee ID attribute in the active directory it is still empty @Theo

Comment: @troya Aha, when posting I left out a singe quote in the filter. Shoiuld be `"mail -eq '$($_.mail)'"` or `"EmailAddress -eq '$($_.mail)'"`. Fixed now

Comment: the output now is `"amyyu@yang.local","1111","Complete"
"test@yang.local","1112","Skipped"`   but the test account employeeID attribute is empty. May I ask why it will skip, sorry I am a newbie to coding.  Is it possible to verify if the ID already exists in AD then it will skip or if the mail address not exist it will show 'The user not existing' ? thanks! @Theo

Comment: @troya OK, I have edited again to show much more output in the console so it tells you why a user got skipped etc. I also took out one of the `try{..} catch{..}` blocks as it was redundant

Comment: The output now are `Field EmployeeID was empty for user 'Yu Amy'. Skipped
The user with email address 'test@yang.local' could not be found
The user with email address 'abc@yang.local' could not be found  ,   'Yu Amy' has empyloeeID i already add it but it shows empty then skipped @Theo , thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: @troya Re-reading your last comment, is the field in your CSV file called `empyloeeID` or is that just a typo in your comment? If that is really the field header, then it will always find that `EmployeeID` is empty because of the typo in the file..

Comment: my excel file is like that `mail,EmployeeID` `amyyu@yang.local,1112` @Theo

Comment: it should be showing `EmployeeID already set to '$($User.EmployeeID)' for user '$($User.Name)'. Skipped"` because i already set it manually to 1112 but it still shows Field EmployeeID was empty for user 'Yu Amy'. Skipped  @Theo

Comment: @troya I left a `!` before `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currentUser.EmployeeID)` which negates the test. That was a leftover from my earlier code. Just remove that `!` and it will run correctly. (already fixed in the answer)

Comment: it is working now! thank you so much !! @Theo